# Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0

Tags: python, flask, cassandra

Exception: **Error from server: code=1100 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'write_type': 'COUNTER', 'consistency': 'LOCAL_ONE'}**

I'm using a three-node Cassandra cluster. after running the application over time. I'm continuously getting seeing exception.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ooc9b.png)

can anyone help me, why am I getting this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Coordinator timeout is commonly a symptom of an under-provisioned/overloaded cluster, or network issues. This timeout is governed by the `cassandra.yaml` settings `*_request_timeout_in_ms`.
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/configuration/cassandra_config_file.html#read-request-timeout-in-ms

You can try raising those, but if the cluster is overloaded you may just end up in worse shape, and pushing timeouts to client timeouts.